# Convert an ByteArray from a JSON to an Image with Java or Spring

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring

I need some help please.
I can get a JSON from an API. This JSON has a pair key value (among others) that contains an array of byte that I need to convert it into an image.
eg:

`{ "id": "63044", "image": "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..........................." }`

I need that image key value to turn it into an image jpg or png.
Is there a way to do it with Java or Spring?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like it's Base64 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `javax.ImageIO` package to achieve this.

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytesdata);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis);
ImageIO.write(imagee, "jpg", new File("output.jpg") );
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write-java.awt.image.RenderedImage-java.lang.String-java.io.File-

Comment: I tried to turn the string into an array of byte with byte [] byteArray = outStreamObj.toByteArray(); but when I set ImageIO.read I get null

Comment: As I said above, the data is Base64 encoded -- you need to decode it to a byte[]

Comment: Yes, thanks. this Base64 stuff gave some insights to look at on Google.